# SDL Delivery service error

Tags: dd4t, discovery

We have a DD4T based application, Our Sites gets down frequently then just comes up after few minutes.

Also When we recycle the app pool, everything starts working just fine. It seems we are losing the connection to the Discovery service. I don't know why but this is happening.

Please see more error info :[image]

Comment: Please add versions - Tridion, DD4T, etc

Comment: See https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Core/issues/100

Comment: It's known issue with  DD4T 2.0, seems quite very often application recycle or caching refreshes happening.
Fix for concurrency issue in JSONSerializerService

Comment: @NunoLinhares We are using DD4T 2.1.4 for DD4T.model , So 2.1 for DD4T and web 8 for tridion.

Comment: @Velmurugan We are using DD4T 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix for concurrency issue in JSONSerializerService

https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.Model/pull/33/commits/ff96b151f06f242989449aa9f84ae7408f358db6

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan ,I am just wondering then how it is working just fine for other application which are using same 2.1.4 for DD4T.Model

Comment: I believe this issue not appearing for all the applications, sometimes it's strange it's not able to reproduce, it would be because of heavy load on the website or based on custom caching functionality or frequent deployment